# ASP.NET model popup Cancel button show in page load

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I'm developing an ASP.net project, I'm using a Modal popup , I have some problems, my Modal popup cancel button show in page load, I'm trying to fix it, but I can't correctly do it, please help me to fix this, I'm trying to used trigger and auto post back, but not working.

[image]

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpConfirm" runat="server" CancelControlID="btnDeleteCancel" DropShadow="true" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" PopupControlID="DivConfirm">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<div class="panel" runat="server" id="DivConfirm">
    <div class="panel-body" style="">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvHelp" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gvHelp_RowCommand" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs" Height="25px" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the `runat="server"` on your div element remove it from the final rendering, or at least changes it? Is there a reason why it is referenced on the server?

Comment: i removed it, but not work,

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpConfirm" runat="server"  DropShadow="true" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" PopupControlID="DivConfirm">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<div class="panel" runat="server" id="DivConfirm">
    <div class="panel-body" style="">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvHelp" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" PageSize="5" OnRowCommand="gvHelp_RowCommand" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removed the CancelControlID="btnDeleteCancel" and delete the cancel button

Comment: Its not a solution, iyou are suggest the remove `CancelControlID`